# Powershell getting same values when using if in foreach

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to get metric from Azure to Zabbix.

The issue is that Metric for VM consists of 2 words:`Percentage CPU`, and Zabbix doesn't allow item keys to consists of 2 words. I also tried `Percentage%20CPU` but getting errors in Zabbix, and I created Zabbix key `percentage_cpu`.

So I decided prior sending data from Zabbix to Azure to "translate" `percentage_cpu` to `Percentage%20CPU`. This works great if only that key is present, but issue starts when I add another key (in this example SQL metric).

For SQL metric all values are in one word - no need to change anything, but then metric for VM is also assigned to SQL. I'm trying to avoid writing separate file for every service

```
     $host_items = Get-ZabbixHostItems -url $zabbix_url -auth $zabbix_auth - 
 zabbix_host $host_name  
    foreach ($host_item in $host_items) 

    { 

        #$host_item_details = select-string -InputObject $host_item.key_ -Pattern '^(azure\.sql)\.(.*)\.(.*)\[\"(.*)\"\]$'; 

        $host_item_details = select-string -InputObject $host_item.key_ -Pattern '^(azure\.\w{2,})\.(.*)\.(.*)\[\"(.*)\"\,(.*)]$'; 

        #$host_item_details = select-string -InputObject $host_item.key_ -Pattern '^(azure)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\[\"(.*)\"\,(.*)]$'; 

        $host_item_provider = $host_item_details.Matches.groups[1]; 

        $host_item_metric = $host_item_details.Matches.groups[2]; 

        $host_item_timegrain = $host_item_details.Matches.groups[3]; 

        $host_item_resource = $host_item_details.Matches.groups[4]; 

        $host_item_suffix = $host_item_details.Matches.groups[5]; 


         if ($host_item_metric='percentage_cpu')
          {$host_item_metric='Percentage%20CPU'}
          else

          { $host_item_metric = $host_item_details.Matches.groups[2];}
      #}



        $uri = "https://management.azure.com{0}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version={1}&interval={2}&timespan={3}&metric={4}" -f ` 

            $host_item_resource, ` 

            "2017-05-01-preview", ` 

            $host_item_timegrain.ToString().ToUpper(), ` 

            $($(get-date).ToUniversalTime().addminutes(-15).tostring("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + "/" + $(get-date).ToUniversalTime().addminutes(-2).tostring("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")), ` 


            $host_item_metric; 


        write-host $uri; 
      }
```

output of hostitems_

```
azure.sql.dtu_consumption_percent.pt1m["/subscriptions/111-222/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/mojsql/databases/test",common]
azure.vm.percentage_cpu.pt1m["/subscriptions/111-222/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/test",common]
```

When I ran code above I'm getting these URI's

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/111-222/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/mojsql/databases/test/providers/microsoft.insights/m
etrics?api-version=2017-05-01-preview&interval=PT1M&timespan=2018-08-11T07:38:05Z/2018-08-11T07:51:05Z&metric=Percentage%20CPU


https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/111-222/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/test/providers/microsoft.insights/metric
s?api-version=2017-05-01-preview&interval=PT1M&timespan=2018-08-11T07:38:05Z/2018-08-11T07:51:05Z&metric=Percentage%20CPU
```

For first link (SQL) metric should be `dtu_consumption` but I'm getting same metric for both links

**Second attempt:**

```
if ($host_item_metric -eq 'percentage_cpu')
          {$host_item_metric='Percentage%20CPU';}
          else

          { $host_item_metric = $host_item_details.Matches.groups[2];}

      write-host $host_item_metric
    }
```

output: (original values)

```
dtu_consumption_percent
percentage_cpu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to use -like

```
if ($host_item_metric -like 'percentage_cpu')
          {$host_item_metric='Percentage%20CPU';}
          else

          { $host_item_metric = $host_item_details.Matches.groups[2]}
```